# How do you round up to nearest multiple of a given factor with floating point numbers?

Tags: java, math, floating-point, ieee-754

The question is how to round a given value to the nearest "almost exact" multiple of a given factor, f. For example:

If f = 2.6, then every "roundUp(x, 2.6)" invocation would return a number from the set {0, +/- 2.6, +/- 2*2.6, +/- 3*2.6, ...}

Typically, my f is either a power of 10 (where the power is positive or negative) or 1/2 said power of 10.

Another example: f = 0.001 , should round up to the nearest integer multiple of 0.001, e.g., {0, +/- 0.001, +/- 2*0.001, +/- 3*0.001}.

UPDATE: I want the result of roundUp(x, f) to be the "ceiling" of the result, that is, the smallest element from the set of multiples greater than or equal to x (if that's the proper way to word it). See my answer below for a not-so-elegant solution (that appears to work for all the cases I can through at it).

All I need is a decent floating point approximation (using double in Java). Any advice greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
double roundUp(double x, double f) {
  return f * Math.ceil(x / f);
}
```

Comment: doesn't work because i don't believe it handles the case where x < 1.0 :(

Comment: that's what i was trying though ... i will post the solution i have now which seems to be working

Comment: what does not work? may be miss under stood you. do you wont the nearest(round), the next(ceil)(pos. direction) or the previous(floor)(neg direction). for me it works as expected roundUp(0.5, 2.6) => 0; roundUp(1.5, 2.6) => 2.6

Comment: how does your roundUp work for roundUp(0.0235, 0.01) ==? 0.03 ? how could i word this to make it clearer? i will amend question with feedback.

Comment: Your function does seem to work - except it rounds down, not always up.

Comment: System.out.println(0.01*Math.round(0.0235/0.01)); => 0.02

Comment: Now I see - your function is brilliant. I want it to do a sort of "ceiling" on the result - instead of roundup(3.041, 0.01) == 3.04, i want the next one, "3.05". It's amazing that the code is so simple ...

Comment: yes, my function rounds to the nearest multiple of f, that is how i understood your question. If you like an always up replace round with ceil, if you want rounding away from zero, use `x < 0 ? floor : ceil` but i don't see a reason for special treating |x| < 1.